# Redis cache strategy

Tags: caching, redis

I'm developing a website to display some kind of articles, just like stackoverflow.

Each article contains title, description, and some frequently changed fields (like view_count).

The website also supports cursor paging(max_id, since_id), filtering(by category, tags).

I want to add a cache layer using Redis. Theres are some choices in my mind:

1. Use zset to store top 1000 acticle id list. Each filter has one zset, like `articles:category:{category_id}` `articles:tag:{tag_id}`. Each zset will be updated when a new article published.

   Use hash to store each article, like `article:{article_id}`

   Update view_count directly in cache for every view, and sync to db at some point.

   Implement cursor paging using `ZRANGEBYSCORE` (score is publishing timestamp).

   - Pros: Never need to expire cache. new article immediately shown.
   - Cons: Difficult to implement and may be error prone. Need some messaging mechanism like rabbitmq.
2. Use database do the filtering and paging, only return id list, cache id list in redis, and set some TTL (10 seconds). Still use hash to cache each article, so view_count can be updated immediately.

   - Pros: Easy to implement, No need to have messaging mechanism. Only id list need to be queried when cache expired.
   - Cons: Need query database for new id list every 10 seconds, new article will be shown after 10 seconds, but view_count will updated immediately.
3. Use redis to cache acticle list for each query, serialize it to json, and set TTL.

   - Pros: Easiest to implement (use spring @Cacheable).
   - Cons: Cache will expire frequently and need query database again. view_count will only be updated when cache expired.

I don't know witch one is a better option, for performance and stability. Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the first option why would you need a messaging mechanism?

Comment: New article may be added by another microservice, zset need subscribe a message to update.